# Laptop screen only turns on when in Linux

Tags: linux, boot, laptop, display, bios

My laptop (Lenovo Yoga 730 13”) has a very strange issue. When turning the laptop on, the screen is black, the backlight stays off. It remains this way for ~15s. Since I dual boot, I’m assuming this is the amount of time GRUB takes to automatically select Ubuntu to boot into. Then the laptop starts as normal, with Linux working fine. By manually changing the boot order in the BIOS, I was able to get windows to boot. Windows (and the BIOS itself) will only output to an external display. I thought it might be a driver issue, so I checked device manager, but windows doesn’t even recognize the laptop screen as a connected device.

Some bootable drives utilize the display, while some don’t. Kali (only bootable drive I had, used it to burn an Ubuntu one) works, as do gparted and Ubuntu. Memtest86 does not, and neither does the bootable media my backup software (Acronis true image 2020) created.

I have since swapped back to the original SSD, but the issue persists.

This all started with a bios update which broke my boot order. After fixing that and getting windows working again, I did the thing I had been trying to do, which was swap the SSD. Somewhere in that process this error occurred.

I tried to install fresh Ubuntu to the new SSD to see if that fixed anything, but the install failed with some squashfs errors, so currently running memtest86 to see if that’s the issue. If not I will burn a new iso to a different flash drive and try again.

I also tried to restore a backup I made before the issue started, but the restore fails. Thanks Acronis.

I have reflashed and reset the bios as well as cleared the CMOS by unplugging the battery.

One thing I noticed when I opened up the laptop is two thermal pads stacked, with the covers still on. They apply pressure to the screen connector on the motherboard. I made the mistake of getting the screen swapped out by Best Buy and I think this was a quick fix to perhaps this very issue. I don’t know why a hardware problem would only appear based on the current OS but maybe someone can shed some light on that.

Anything that could go wrong seems to have; I am at a total loss. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried Enabling the Internal Graphics in UEFI?

Comment: @vssher That doesn’t seem to be an option in the BIOS. The laptop doesn’t have a discrete graphics card.

Comment: @vssher Found the problem- the screen connector is indeed loose from the motherboard. I put a folded up lore card in as a temporary fix and it’s working again.